# Nexus 6 screen goes black during call (w/ Lollipop 5.1)

Tags: calls, screen, 5.1-lollipop, proximity-sensor

After updating to Lollipop 5.1, any phone calls made turns the screen off. I cannot get the phone to bring up the screen to end the call, dial another person, or interact with the screen in any way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [known problem](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/nexus/nexus-6/mIRwBP4Hx_Y%5B1-25%5D) with the current Android 5.1 update and screen protectors. The problem is related to screen protectors affecting proximity sensing that normally turns off the screen when it is close to your face. There are a couple of solutions:

- Remove the screen protector
- Set the **Power Button Ends Call** setting under **Settings > Accessibility**.

Comment: FYI: I did get the Android 5.1.1 update as mentioned in the link and that seemed to have fixed the issue. I side loaded Android 6 and the issue is back. I wonder if that patch did not make it through to the Marshmallow build. So if you are thinking about upgrading, I would hold off. Also as another workaround I read that plugging in a headset will keep your screen on.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a "duh", but I've found that using a blue tooth headset also prevents this problem from occurring.